# How do you construct an object that can throw exception?

Tags: c++, class, oop, exception, error-handling

This is going to go out of scope so I can't use it.

```cpp
try
{
    SomeClass someObject({});
}
catch (std::exception & e)
{

}

someObject(x); // someObject does not exist because it goes out of scope
```

Comment: move usage into try statement block

Comment: .......but... but... potentially hundreds of lines of code needs to go in there. Isn't that bad? Edit: ok maybe 10s of lines...

Comment: think of it as "I'm wrapping existing lines around with try {}"

Comment: pfft *shrug* alright then! I'll go with that.

Comment: If the default constructor is `noexcept`, and it has one, of course, you can define the variable outside the `try` block, then copy assign it inside the `try` block. But, if construction throws, do you really want to continue?

Comment: Those hundreds of lines of code should be in a function. The function should contain all of the code that depends on that object. The `try` block goes in the code that calls that function, or in the code that calls that code, or somewhere even higher up the call chain, where that failure can be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a useful application of [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

```
std::optional<SomeClass> maybe_someobject;

try {
     maybe_someobject.emplace( /* Constructor parameters go here */);
} catch (...  /* or something specific */)
{
     /* catch exceptions */
     return; // Do not pass "Go". Do not collect $200.
}

SomeClass &someobject=maybe_someobject.value();

// Use someobject normally, at this point. Existing code will have to look
// very hard to be able to tell the difference.
```

This adds a little bit overhead, but it's quite minimal, but you preserve complete type and RAII-safety.

Answer (score 1):

Construct the object dynamically, eg:

```cpp
SomeClass *someObject = nullptr;

try
{
    someObject = new SomeClass(...);
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{

}

// or:
// SomeClass *someObject = new(nothrow) SomeClass(...);

if (someObject)
{
    // use someObject as needed...
    delete someObject;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> someObject;

try
{
    someObject.reset(new SomeClass(...));
    // or:
    // someObject = std::make_unique<SomeClass>(...);
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{

}

if (someObject)
{
    // use someObject as needed...
}
```